# factory not being found in PHP Feature Test Laravel-8

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-8

Just playing around with laravel-8 unit tests. I extended the basic TestCase and thought laravels factory method would be available. I checked the composer.json and the factories are being loaded.

I am trying to run this particular test but `factory` is not found any ideas:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\User;

class LoginControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    /** @test */
    public function login_authenticates_and_redirects_user()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $response = $this->post(route('login'), [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);

        $response->assertRedirect(route('home'));
        $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginControllerTest::login_authenticates_and_redirects_user
Error: Call to undefined function Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth\factory()
```

Comment: [Shouldn't it be User::factory()?](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. On laravel 8 models are at 'App\Models\'.
2. It changes how factory works. See at [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#has-many-relationships).

So, it should be like:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Models\User;

class LoginControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
    /** @test */
    public function login_authenticates_and_redirects_user()
    {
        $user = User::factory->create();

        $response = $this->post(route('login'), [
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'password'
        ]);

        $response->assertRedirect(route('home'));
        $this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in upgrading to laravel-8 release notes:

- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#seeder-factory-namespaces

"Laravel's model factories feature has been totally rewritten to support classes and is not compatible with Laravel 7.x style factories."

So in order to make it work I used:

```
$user = \App\Models\User::factory(User::class)->make();
```

Comment: That should just be `User::factory()->make();`